# HTML Editor Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a html editor plugin for my application My requirement is I need to see a preview while I'm typing in the textbox like the question field in stack over flow I tried some plugins but they didnt support the preview function... Is anyone know something please share..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these plugins:

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Both these tools have supported preview feature.